# Reset ADO.NET schema

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, odp.net

I modified a schema (set a field to be non-nullable), but when I try to recreate the mapping with ADO.NET I only see the old schema.

The .edmx file looks like this:

```
        <EntityType Name="STG_DW_BUF_CODE_D">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="BUF_CODE_KEY" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="BUF_CODE_KEY" Type="number" Nullable="false" />

…
      <EntityType Name="STG_DW_REGION_D">
        <Property Name="REGION_KEY" Type="number" />
```

The STG_DW_REGION_D view should have Nullable="false" like the view above it.

I can confirm the new schema has this field non-nullable through another SQL application, but I can't get ADO.NET to notice.

I tried erasing the model and recreating it. I tried closing visual studio and starting it up again. It still sees the old schema.

Does anyone know how to reset it? Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not clear what you are up to. Are you using ModelFirst or DatabaseFirst? When you say "I modified a schema" - what schema you modified? How you modified it? What database are you using? What are you referring to "ADO.NET" in the "can't get ADO.NET to notice" fragment?

Comment: @Pawel: DatabaseFirst, of the Oracle variety. I set a field to be non-nullable so Linq would pick it up as the PK. I am referring to ADO.NET because when I create the ADO.NET object from a database it tries to model the relation in a class that doesn't have the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is either a bug in ADO.NET or ODP (Oracle's connection to Linq). If you add a field it will remove the cached schema and pull in a new schema with *updated* field attributes.